# Core-drawer-panel with two display modes?

Tags: polymer

What I'd like to do is create something that works like a core-drawer-panel in narrow (phone) display mode, with a hiding left-side overlay menu that can be swiped out or brought out using a button press (which is what core-drawer-panel does currently).

However, when the component is in a wide display, core-drawer-panel locks open and shows the menu on the left and cannot be disabled.

What I would like to do is add further functionality in the wide screen mode that lets the user collapse the side-nav down to either nonexistent (good) or an alternate view which ends up being a lot skinnier (best). My thinking is: the full-width menu in a wide screen has a lot of (icon)+(name) entries for site navigation, but the menu could collapse down to just a list of (icon) and be narrower if the user wants.

I'm not even sure where I'd start poking at the core-drawer-panel template, css, and other attributes to make something like this, so I'm using this as a working project to better understand how these core components work.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when the component is in a wide display, core-drawer-panel locks open and shows the menu on the left and cannot be disabled.

`<core-drawer-panel forceNarrow>` will prevent this from happening.

Comment: Ah, this helps, maybe I can combine that with just a different manual, conditionally-rendered narrow menu.